# implement canny edge detection algorithm in matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing

i try to implement canny edge detection algorithm in matlab. it work fine when i use matlab in built image cameraman.tif but it give error when i use different image and command window show:

Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in canny_edge (line 45)

```
            sum = sum + (ID(u+i, v+j) * filter(i+3, j+3));
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgYU7.png)

whole matlab code is hosted at [link](http://freetexthost.com/02p1qkc3wr)
i am novice in matlab. i try to implement algorithm for college assignment

Comment: Please capitalize at least people's names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%figure,imshow(filter);
for u = 3 : r
    for v = 3 : c
        sum = 0;
        for i = -2 : 2
            for j = -2 : 2
                sum = sum + (ID(u+i, v+j) * filter(i+3, j+3));
            end
        end
        IDx(u,v) = sum;
    end
end
```

Comment: thanks daniel R but now it show three consecutive edge detecting images shown http://i.imgur.com/i2KRxUT.jpg?1 how i handle that one

Comment: Looks like your image has 3 colour channels, your code seems to be for grayscale only.

Comment: but image is black & white

Comment: Set a breakpoint, check it. It depends on your input, not on the code.