# Is there a way to do edge detection by Canny algorithm in matlab?

Tags: matlab, canny-operator

I want to implement canny edge detection algorithm in matlab, I found some source but they only give example of 1 image like [this] [implement canny edge detection algorithm in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20308813/implement-canny-edge-detection-algorithm-in-matlab). what I want is to implement the algorithm to sets of image in a folder. Is that possible?

Comment: Are you asking how to reuse the code for the algorithm?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/matlab/matlab_functions.htm

Comment: Use the `edge` function in the Image Processing Toolbox: https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/edge.html — Don’t rely on random code you find online unless you know what you’re expecting to come out of it. That linked question does not contain any code to compute the Canny edge detector.